# ComponentInfo GridLayout error only in emulator

Tags: java, android, gridview, layout-inflater

I made an Android App and on **every hardware device** I tested it, **it runs**. This goes from 2.1.x to 4.2. But now I wanted to make sure, that it looks good on every screen size, so I tried the app in different emulators.

No single emulator configuration could run this app and I cant understand why. I always get this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{*class*}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #325: Error inflating class android.widget.GridLayout
```

I think most of the error code is uneccessary to post, but there are 5 lines like this

```
E/AndroidRuntime(425):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:724)
```

I would understand an app that runs only in emulators (I once had this problem until I went to usb debugging with "real" devices), but an app that only gets along with real devices seems a bit weird to me. Someone has an idea?

**EDIT**

Lots of people have this error because of RAM problems, but my app uses not more than 5 MB

Comment: What is your code for the xml layout?

Comment: that for asking. it is too long to add but i have a question. Might an empty table bring up this problem?